# Series regulator with op-amp damaging power transistors

Tags: power-supply, transistors, voltage-regulator, power-electronics, series

Hello my name is Juliana, I am facing a problem with my project for a 2A linear adjustable power supply
When it is configured with a voltage lower than 65V and current higher than 1.3A, the power transistors simply short circuit. I believe that the transistors (2sc2555) enter the second breakdown zone, but I'm not sure.
I intend to replace them with the 2sc3451, however I have doubts, I would be grateful if anyone has any ideas.

[image]

[image]

Comment: The lower Vout, the higher the power disspation. At 65V and 2A each transistor will dissipate 40watts. You need more transistors or better heat sinks. BTW your LTspice simulation has 2-15V sources connected anti parallel

Answer (score 1):

You need to do proper thermal calculations and design, for the worst case power dissipation. The following overview is NOT worst case, but to illustrate the idea.

With 125VDC on the input side of the regulator, and (say) 65V out at 1A, the power dissipated by the three transistors is (125 - 65) x 1 = 60W. If we assume (and this will not be true, but OK for a first approximation) that the three devices share current equally, that is 20W per device.

Now you need to design so that the transistor die does not melt at a worst case ambient temperature (which is what is causing the failures you see now). Let's say 100 degrees with ambient temperature at 30. That means that there is a temperature difference of 70 degrees at 20W, so you need to arrange heatsinking to give at least 70/20 = 3.5deg/W.

Now you must select a heatsink such that the TOTAL thermal resistance from transistor die to air is no greater than that amount. (You can look up the thermal resistance from the die to the body of the device on the datasheet.)

This is the basic process. However, take note of the following:

- 65V at 1A is probably not your worst case. If you want to go down to (say) 30V, things are more difficult.
- the devices will not share current perfectly. This is due to variations in gain from device to device, and also variations in R014/105/106. The difference may not be much, but it would be wise to take a look - you can do this by measuring current through each device (voltage across the emitter resistors).
- if you mount the three devices on the same heatsink, the calculation is a little more complex as they are sharing the path to free air.
- in general it pays to be a bit conservative with heat design. If the numbers seem a bit close to the edge, the unit is likely to fail in extended use. Once a device starts to hit thermal runaway it will fail.
- make a prototype and do some real measurements with a thermistor on the transistor body and the heatsink to verify that your calculations are in the right area. In particular look for a stable temperature at your worst case which is in line with your numbers. Run the prototype into a load at worst case for several hours and check that temperature stabilises at a safe value.